# Restarting app without worrying about onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, application-design, object-persistence

How do I simply just restart my ENTIRE app instead of trying to worry about saving the instance perfectly in **onSaveInstanceState** and reinitializing everything perfectly when resumed/restored in **onRestoreInstanceState**? (this can quickly become error prone)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by linear programming, but that's a math term

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 10.1.16**

I chose to do this in **onCreate** since onRestoreInstanceState behaves oddly sometimes.

This method is based on the fact that the onCreate(**Bundle**) is null unless the activity is being *revived* in which case it is whatever **onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)** set it to.

I set TWO flags.  One in **onSaveInstanceState** in the Bundle so to know that it is a valid Bundle set by me.  The other in the class itself to determine if **onCreate** was called because of *recreation* or *rotation*.  And so in **onCreate** I checked to see if **onSaveInstanceState** is not null, check the Bundle flag, and check **bInit** (which defaults to false).  If both flags are true then it means android dumped and destroyed our apps memory and the safest way to ensure everything is initialized again in a linear-style application is to just restart it and launch the beginning activity.

```
public class SomeMiddleActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static boolean bInit = false; // only way it will be false again is if android cleared our memory and we are recreating

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state)
    {
        // set a flag so that onCreate knows this is valid
        state.putBoolean("StateSaved", true);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // this must be called first always for some reason
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("StateSaved", false) && !bInit)
            {
                // we were recreated... start app over
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Startup.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }

        bInit = true; // this will stay true until android has cleared our memory

        .......
    }
```

Hope this helps someone and although this has worked thus far, if anyone has a different suggestion let me know.

*And FYI:* the **onSaveInstanceState(Bundle, PersistableBundle)** version  of **onSaveInstanceState** is never called ever so I dont know why they even  implement it. (?)

REFERENCES:

ACCORDING TO ANDROID DOCUMENTATION

> onCreate
>
> Bundle: If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut down then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it is null.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I simply just restart my app instead of trying to worry about saving the instance

You mean the current activity? Do nothing (Don't implement `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`).

The activity gets created automatically when changes happen. If there is no saved instance state, the activity won't restore any data.

Edit:

I think I came across similar issue too few weeks earlier, where I've to kill all the activities in the back stack and open a fresh new activity.

```
// Start Main Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
finishAffinity();
startActivity(intent);
```

Use `finishAffinity()`. This works on > API 16.

When you kill all the activities in the back stack and open the main activity, it is kind of similar to restarting your app.

Comment: no... restart the ENTIRE application assuming we are already past the main (beginning) activity.

Answer (score 0):

**Try implementing this way**

```
private final String IS_RE_CREATED = "is_re_created";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(IS_RE_CREATED, true);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(IS_RE_CREATED)) {
        boolean isRecreated = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IS_RE_CREATED, false);
        if (isRecreated) restartApplication(this);
    }
}

public void restartApplication(Context context) {

    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    // Intent to start launcher activity and closing all previous ones
    Intent restartIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    restartIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    restartIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    context.startActivity(restartIntent);

    // Kill Current Process
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Note: It is not a recommended to forcefully restart application.